# Combined attraction pass for Moscow and St Petersburg

Tags: russia, sightseeing, moscow

I know of separate attraction (city cards) passes for Moscow and St Petersburg, but was wondering if a combined pass exists that I can use both in  Moscow and St Petersburg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pass City](https://passcity.ru) seems to offer this, although I haven't tried it myself so can't vouch for it.

The website lists 91 places in Moscow and 59 places in St Petersburg that the pass can be used, but some users have complained that the pass wasn't accepted in several places.

Also, the reviews are quite [mixed](https://www.tripadvisor.com/AttractionProductReview-g298484-d12469569-Moscow_CityPass-Moscow_Central_Russia.html), often suggesting that it's better value to just pay for the specific museums and attractions that you're interested in.

Comment: This pass certainly looks more like a burden than a blessing. You'll still have to wait in line to buy tickets with the "pass" (which is actually a credit card with a custom design), but this time you may have to explain to the ticket office clerk, possibly in Russian, that the pass entitles you to a free entry, or spend time trying to reach their support in the not-so-unlikely scenario the pass doesn't work for whatever reason. I appreciate that you've highlighted these points in your answer!